# ¿Como saber el tamaño real de un overflow-x auto?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Estoy intentando crear unos tabs que al sobrepasarse de tamaño aparezca un icono de una flecha para que se desplacen.
Para hacer esto en el contenedor padre utilizo un overflo-x: auto,
Y he creado este método en el js para bindear un propiedad y hacer que aparezca o no la flecha.

```
setTabsWidth()
    {
        if (this.$refs.tablist.scrollwidth > this.$refs.tablist.clientWidth)
        {
            this.showArrow = true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            this.showArrow = false;
        }
    }
```

El caso es que el scrolltwidth no me funciona en los dispositivos mas pequeños y no se como calcular ese espacio  de desbordamiento, para poder bindear la clase.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¿Podrías compartir el código completo, o al menos el HTML, para poder ver qué necesitas exactamente para hacer ese trabajo?

Answer (score 0):

Aqui varias cosas, tienes que ser un tanto creativo para este tipo de cosas y trata de hacer esto como un uso reutilizable para futuros trabajos.

El problema en pantallas pequeñas es el viewpor de las mismas.

Lo otro es que en la capa con scroll horizontal tienes que usar display:flex, así le puedes sacar a una capa padre el width total del mismo.

Comment: Hola Nelson. Yo creo que estoy llamando la función en el sitio equivocado o algo porque cuando pruebo en la consola si me da los valores correctos, la estoy llamando en el mounted ¿Puede ser eso? Mil gracias

Comment: Recuerda que cuando ejecutas una acción en el DOM este tiene que estar cargado, de lo contrario dará undefined porque el navegador detecta que no existe a la hora de disparar la acción o el evento depende, también pudiera haber un error de compatibilidad en otro lugar del código que hace que en vista móvil en el navegador y versión del mismo donde pruebas de error